# Is it possible to import a font inline without using the <style> or <link> tags

Tags: html, css

I completely understand that this is not how don't importing is supposed to be done. I recognize that it's gonna be hack-y if it's possible. The blog I post to has 5 horrible font options, and I want Roboto. The blog automatically removes  and  tags from my page. Is there any other way to import the font into the html?

Comment: Look into loading the font as a base64 embed.

Comment: if no tag allowed, I don't think so...

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, you can use below option

```
<div style="@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;">
  test message
</div>
```

Codepen for reference- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KmzveZ

Comment: that actually doesn't work unfortunately. If you remove the "sans-serif' line after 'Roboto' in your codepen, the text returns to normal

Comment: @Acoustic77  font-family has to be added after importing , if you remove, it will  become normal font

Comment: google fonts -https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto+Condensed

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed `<script>` tags, you could write some javascript that could document.write the appropriate code.  But, I'm guess you're not allowed to do that either.

Comment: I wouldn't use `document.write`. Create a `style` tag and append it instead.